# WPF Animation Optimization

Tags: wpf, animation

I've seen a lot of these questions around, but most focus on Windows XP, and none of the solutions work for me.

I'm running a really simple application with really simple animations (sliding, zoom in / zoom out, fade in / fade out, grow / shrink, etc), and most animations are choppy (specially the ones that slide the whole screen). At first I thought it was because the ListViews in the screens had data, so I removed the data just to test and no improvement. Also the computer I'm trying it on is not that bad, it's an i5 processor with a GeForce GT 330M so I would think it would run smoothly there.

I've tried it in a really high-end gaming computer, and in there it works fine, but I don't think the application I'm doing should really need a high end computer to be rendered ok, I repeat, it's really simple.

Are there any general optimizations I can do? I looked online [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa970683.aspx) and in other places, and I've already done most of the optimization.

Anyway, any suggestion will be greatly appreciated, we want of course the application to run in a regular user computer (maybe dual core with win 7 and low end graphics card at the very least).

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

How are you animating?  If you are using Storyboards and built-in WPF animations, then you should be fine- I'd suggest checking the rendering tier that your machine scores- see here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms742196.aspx.  If you are using timers or manual animations of some sort, I'd suggest moving to the built-in animations available in WPF.

Comment: I'm using built-in WPF animations (created in blend), they are pretty simple enough to state them in a sentence: "from 0:0:0 to 0:0:0.50, make ScaleX go from 1 to 1.3 then repeat with ScaleY". But they're still choppy, although animations on small items are better than animations on big items with controls in them. Perhaps having 'too many' controls can cause this? If so, I'll have to find out how many is too many...

Comment: You may want to put the app under a profiler.  My personal preference is jetBrains dotTrace, but there are a bunch of good ones out there that will tell you where the time is being spent.  My guess is that your app is spending a lot of time re-measuring.  The one other suggestion would be to make sure that your problem machine has the latest and greatest graphics drivers- they can make a huge difference in WPF, especially if you are using HW rendering.